# How can I store the value of an input in javascript as soon as it gains focus?

Tags: javascript, variables, input, focus

If a have an input field with some value, how can I store the value of that input as soon as it gains focus? This must be done before value of the field changes. 
I have tried `onfocus()` but I'm getting stuck in some kind of loop.

```
<input type="text" value="someValue" onFocus="storeVal(this.value)" >
<script>
function storeVal(val){alert(val);}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to put your value in a hidden label? Then you can check whenever you want with the new value in the inputfield and the hidden label that holds the original value?

Comment: Declare a variable outside and do: `var oldValue;
function storeVal(val) { oldValue = val; }` and then you can access it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function storeVal(ele){
  ele.blur(); // unfocus
  alert(ele.value);
}
```

when the alert closes it will bring back the state. so it will focus the element again. "WHILE TRUE ;)"

```
<input type="text" value="someValue" onFocus="storeVal(this)" >
```

Little change of HTML to make it easier

Comment: This is right, but perhaps instead of using `blur`, just log it out to the console, ie `function storeVal(val) { console.log(val); }`. That should prevent the input from losing focus.

Comment: Sure it all depends on what is needed